# Landing page of salesforce1 as a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, landing-page, salesforce1-platform

Is there any way to set Salesforce1 landing page as a custom lightning component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

1) Expose the Lightning Component as a [custom tab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm) in SF 1

2) Make your component as the first item in the Navigation menu's Selected list, it becomes the default landing page in SF1.

Here's the exact text from the above article.

> In the navigation menu, items appear in the order you specify. The
>   first item in the Selected list becomes your users’ Salesforce1
>   landing page.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Same is mentioned in this Link :https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm